# JavaFX ColorPicker won't bring up CustomColor pop-up dialog box

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx

So I'm currently working on the GUI for one of my projects and I'm trying to set up a JavaFX ColorPicker to allow the user to set the fill color of a rectangle. The ColorPicker appears and allows the user to select one of the default colors, however whenever the user clicks on the "Custom Color" link that should open up the Custom Color pop-up dialog box, a NullPointerException is raised. I currently have it set up that when the user right clicks the rectangle, a ContextMenu appears with one MenuItem that contains the ColorPicker.

```
ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
MenuItem changeColor = new MenuItem();
ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
contextMenu.getItems().add(changeColor);
changeColor.setGraphic(colorPicker);

for(int i = 0; i < customColors.getChildren().size(); i++) {
        customColors.getChildren().get(i).setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                selectedRectangle.setStrokeWidth(1);
                selectedRectangle = (Rectangle)e.getSource();
                ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
                ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStrokeWidth(4);
                ColorPaletteModel.getInstance().setSelectedIndex(16+customColors.getChildren().indexOf(e.getSource()));
                if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
                    contextMenu.show((Rectangle)e.getSource(),Side.TOP,0,0);
                }
            }
        });
```

This is the Exception thread that appears when you try to click the "Custom Colors" link:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NullPointerException
at javafx.stage.Window$9.invalidated(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.markInvalid(Unknown Source)
at javafx.beans.property.BooleanPropertyBase.set(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Window.setShowing(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Window.show(Unknown Source)
at javafx.stage.Stage.show(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.CustomColorDialog.show(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ColorPalette$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.ColorPalette$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.control.Hyperlink.fire(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$141(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication$$Lambda$37/1558600329.run(Unknown Source)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Any help at all would be great. Thanks.

EDIT: I upgraded to Java 8.25 but it didn't help. It seems that the problem might lie in how I'm putting the ColorPicker inside of a MenuItem inside of a ContextMenu, because I tried the ColorPicker in an empty frame and it worked fine. Below is an MCVE example that shows he issue.

```
package test;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.geometry.Side;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.scene.control.ContextMenu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseButton;
import javafx.scene.input.MouseEvent;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    primaryStage.setTitle("Test");

    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(25,25,Color.LIGHTGREY);
    ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker();
    ContextMenu contextMenu = new ContextMenu();
    MenuItem changeColor = new MenuItem();

    changeColor.setGraphic(colorPicker);
    contextMenu.getItems().add(changeColor);

    rect.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
        @Override
        public void handle(MouseEvent e){
            ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStroke(Color.BLACK);
            ((Rectangle)e.getSource()).setStrokeWidth(4);
            if(e.getButton() == MouseButton.SECONDARY){
                contextMenu.show((Rectangle)e.getSource(),Side.TOP,0,0);
            }
        }
    });

    StackPane root = new StackPane();
    root.getChildren().add(rect);
    primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 250));
    primaryStage.show();
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    launch(args);
}
}
```

Comment: Maybe you are encountering a fixed bug, e.g. [RT-27002 ColorPicker - opening the Custom Color dialog fails if the control's value is set to null](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-27002).  Try a recent version of JavaFX (if you are not using one already), e.g. [Java 8u25](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/javase/index-jsp-138363.html) or an early access version of [Java 8u40](https://jdk8.java.net/download.html).

Comment: If the issue still exists, create an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), so that somebody could reproduce the issue and create a bug report in the [JavaFX issue tracker](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/secure/Dashboard.jspa).